# What direction type to choose to sort by boolean field in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

What kind of direction to choose to sort by boolean field? Is it correct to write 'ASC' to sort by boolean field?

```
sortInfo : this.promotionMode ? null : {
            field : 'autoInvited', //it is boolean field
            direction : 
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it correct to write 'ASC' to sort by boolean field?

There is nothing wrong with it. With `ASC` direction, `FALSE`s will come first followed by `TRUE`s.